# Adding things to NSUserDefaults - multiple views

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a dictionary-like app and I want to store the user's search history using NSUserDefaults. I created a `seaechHistory` array outside the class. Now I am appending the `searchHistory` array and save it using NSUserDefaults in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and I retrieve the stored history in a history view. The storage worked fine but when I re-run the app the NSUserDefaults set the `seachHistory` to the empty array and thus I lost all the saved data. The `synchronize()` method does work anywhere.

Initial View Controller:

```
 import UIKit

var searchHistory = [String]()


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func textFieldDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableView.hidden = false
        searchManager.updateFilter(textField.text)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func tapOnTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

        let textFieldLength = count(textField.text)

        if textFieldLength == 0 {
            tableView.hidden = true

        } else {
        tableView.hidden = false
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        tableView.hidden = true

        self.textField.delegate = self

    }


    var searchManager = SearchManager()


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchManager.filteredURLCount()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel!.text = searchManager.filteredURLAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        self.textField.text = searchManager.filteredURLAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        searchHistory.append(textField.text)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(searchHistory, forKey: "History")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cellTapped", sender: "Cell")

        textField.text = nil
        tableView.hidden = true
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return indexPath
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.tableView.hidden = true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "cellTapped" {
        var DestViewController: definitionView = segue.destinationViewController as! definitionView
        DestViewController.searchWord = textField.text
        } 
    }


}
```

History View Controller:

```
    import UIKit

class historyView: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchHistory  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("History")! as! [String]
        println(searchHistory)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var destination: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

    }

}
```

Comment: What you get is exactly what I would expect according to your code. Your code starts with an empty array every time you start the app. On the other hand, you seem to know exactly how to read the saved dictionary. So why don't you do that when you initialise the array?

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks, but how do I do that? Do I get the saved data and save it again? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your array in viewDidLoad() method, then it won't be empty.

Add tihs code in your ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchHistory = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("History")! as! [String]
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks, but it only works when I load the history view controller prior to looking up a word, if I look up a work directly after I re-run the app, the history is lost again. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the whole code that I can better understand your problem?

Comment: You have to add this line of code to your initial VC viewDidLoad method, not to history VC. `searchHistory = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("History")! as! [String]`

Comment: Haha, I've fixed it and it worked! Thank you very much smart guy!

Comment: @mikle94 NSUserDefaults has a method called stringArrayForKey. No need to cast from object to string array. You should NOT for unwrap and it may crash your app. I recommend using if let and stringArrayForKey. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringArrayForKey:

Comment: @mikle94 A further issue: I added   `if searchHistory.count != 0 { searchHistory = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("History")! as! [String] } `to the ViewDidLoad in the initial VC to avoid crash when I first run the app on a new phone, but then if I re-run the app the stored history is gone again.

Comment: Try not to check for `searchHistory.count == 0`. Try `if let history = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("History") { searchHistory = history }`